# Electron + Angular 2: Sharing a constants.js file

Tags: angular, electron

So I'm creating a desktop app using electron and Angular 2+ is my front-end. I want to share a javascript file between the front-end code AND the electron code. I really only want constants to be defined that I'll be using in both places.

For example, when communicating with Angular2 using electron's ipcMain, you would do something like this:

```
// electron-main.js
const constants = require('./electron-scripts/constants.js');
....
ipcMain.on('load-data', (event, data) => { 
    event.sender.send(constants.SOME_CHANNEL, doSomethingWithData(data));
});
....


// angular-electron.service.ts
import { SOME_CHANNEL } from 'electron-constants';
...
this.ipcRenderer.on(SOME_CHANNEL, (event, payload) => { ... });
...
```

My question is... how can I create the `electron-constants` module so that I can share the string constant `SOME_CHANNEL` between Angular2 TS files and electron js files?

I tried doing something like this:

```
// typings.d.ts
declare module 'electron-constants' { export const SOME_CHANNEL: string }

// angular-cli.json
...
scripts: ['../electron-scripts/constants.js']
...

// electron-scripts/constants.js
module.exports.SOME_CHANNEL = 'some-channel';
```

But that doesn't work at all. Has anyone tried to do this?

Comment: Did you ever have any joy with this? I'm looking at doing something similar and can't get it to work